# Image gallery selector for html form via PHP

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a text field and I want to add a link to an image gallery.  The user clicks the image they want and the gallery closes and the text field is set to the image id they chose.

How do I accomplish this using PHP?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, no, I don't really understand the question.

Comment: this has nothing to do with PHP as it is a server side programming language. But can be accomplished using javascript if you use a popup. retagged.

Comment: Do you have an example of a site where you've seen this?

Comment: Why the question title changed ?

Answer (score 1):

You dont need PHP to do those. YOu can use a simple html / javascript as follows

form.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
var windowReference;
function openPopup() {
windowReference = window.open('images.html','imagewindow');
windowReference.opener = self;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="formName">
<input onclick="openPopup();" type="textbox" name="test" value="" id="image-1"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

images.html

```
<script>
function setvalue(imgid) {
console.log(window.opener);
window.opener.document.getElementById('image-1').value = imgid;
window.close();
 }
</script>
<img src="image-1.jpg" onclick="setvalue(1)" />
<img src="image-2.jpg" onclick="setvalue(2)" />
```

Comment: Thanks man, if i want to use the jquery popup box, how should i do as simple way. fancy box is so complex way for my case. haha.

Answer (score 0):

The question makes enough sense if you read between the lines. You need to use both `jquery` and a popup tool such as `fancybox`. The only PHP involved is on the page opened in the `fancybox`.

Comment: Sorry, my case question maybe some special. If i want to do that, what should i do, fancy box just image of jquery, but my case is textfield

Comment: no, fancybox would open (via ajax) a PHP page with your table of images. when clicked, javascript would copy the id of the image, close the fancybox, then paste the id into your text input.

Comment: From what I can tell, he doesn't even need a lightbox plugin (thought it would look nicer), he's just looking for how to pass query strings back and forth (which doesn't require PHP or JS)

Comment: @tommychoo : Are you trying to provide a list of images, the user chooses the one they like, and that image id is then submitted in a form? For something like what they want their icon to be or background image, etc?